# Entity Framework exception for parameters that have 'allow nulls' enabled

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am adding a new register into the SQL Server database using Entity Framework like this:

```
var configSlot = new DeviceConfig_DB
                     {
                         ID_DeviceConfig = 95,
                         ConfigName = configName,
                         ParamName = "Param1",
                         ParamValue = "1000",
                         ToolName = null,
                         ToolValue = null,
                     };
```

It returns a validation error exception because of `ToolName` and `ToolValue` fields, and only are accepted if I set a string value (that fields are `nvarchar`).

If I insert a new register using a SQL Server Management Studio query, it is accepted even if I don't provide those fields. They do have the 'allow nulls' option.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DeviceConfig_DB] ([ID_DeviceConfig], [ConfigName], [ParamName], [ParamValue])
VALUES (96, 'test', 'Param1', '1000')
```

How can I insert a new register with Entity Framework with null values for those fields?

EDIT:
Here is the DeviceConfig_DB class

```
  public partial class DeviceConfig_DB
    {
        public int ID_DeviceConfig { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ID_PhysicalDevice { get; set; }
        public string ConfigName { get; set; }
        public string ParamName { get; set; }
        public string ParamValue { get; set; }
        public string ToolName { get; set; }
        public string ToolValue { get; set; }
    
        public virtual PhysicalDevice_DB PhysicalDevice_DB { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The validation error is not the database rejecting your insert but the internal mismatch in EF between your object and the metadata that defines it. Go take a look at your mapping definition in EF and check how these two columns are defined there.

Comment: Please show us the `DeviceConfig_DB` class in your C# project

Comment: Added the DeviceConfig_DB class as requested. Aha, probably there is a mismatch because of non Nullable<string>. I am testing it...